# Duplicated rows means with original variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm currently working on a dataset generated during a lab experiment where observations where doubled (measured two times).

I have `ID` of the observed object, the `value` of the results, the `type` of object and the `hour` it was measured (+120 other categorical, character and numeric variables that I want to mean). Here is a simplified data frame :

```
    library(dplyr)
    A <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4)
    B <-  A*2.5+(rnorm(2,A[A],sd = 0.2))
    C <- c("banana","banana","poireau","poireau","melon","melon","kiwi")
    D <- c("H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","H7")

    df <-data_frame(ID=as.integer(A),value=B,type=factor(C), hour=as.character(D))

    df

# A tibble: 7 x 4
     ID     value    type  hour
  <int>     <dbl>  <fctr> <chr>
1     1  3.337352  banana    H1
2     1  3.398814  banana    H2
3     2  5.837352 poireau    H3
4     2  5.898814 poireau    H4
5     3  8.337352   melon    H5
6     3  8.398814   melon    H6
7     4 10.837352    kiwi    H7
```

My goal is to compute de mean of values by ID in order to keep only one value, one ID but still keep the others variables. what I tried was :

```
 df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_if(is.double, mean)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID     value
  <int>     <dbl>
1     1  3.368083
2     2  5.868083
3     3  8.368083
4     4 10.837352
```

as you can see, dplyr respond to my command: it means only double values, but how can I keep other columns ?

as for the `hour` field, I am wishing to keep the first value in the table. the desired output would be :

```
     # A tibble: 4 x 4
     ID `mean(value)`    type    hour
  <int>         <dbl>   <fctr>  <chr>
1     1      3.368083   banana    H1
2     2      5.868083  poireau    H3
3     3      8.368083    melon    H5
4     4     10.837352     kiwi    H7
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `mutate_if` and then use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate_if(is.double, mean) %>%
   distinct(ID, value, .keep_all = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
#     ID     value    type  hour
#   <int>     <dbl>   <fctr> <chr>
#1     1  3.368083  banana    H1
#2     2  5.868083 poireau    H3
#3     3  8.368083   melon    H5
#4     4 10.837352    kiwi    H7
```

Comment: Thank you ! what I used for my 130+ variables was : 
`df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate_if(is.double, mean) %>% distinct(ID, is.double, .keep_all=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Is it important, that you only mean over `double` variables? Here is a code, that works for your example:

```
 df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(value = mean(value), type = first(type), hour = first(hour))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
     ID     value    type  hour
    <int>     <dbl>  <fctr> <chr>
1     1  3.312154  banana    H1
2     2  5.812154 poireau    H3
3     3  8.312154   melon    H5
4     4 10.690296    kiwi    H7
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's a way of doing it, but I have 135 variables of the 3 kind. So I was hoping I could get something that works automatically with variable type.